# print from resources (resw) directly in view on uwp | WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, resources, win-universal-app

Hi guys i'm building a Universal Windows App for windows 10 IOT.
So, I'didn't found a method to get a label value from resources file, directly from WPF.

There is a method like this:

```
<Button Content="{x:StaticResources local:mylabel" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="btnUpdate" Margin="0,200,0,0" MinWidth="300" Command="{Binding add}" />
```

on the "normal" WPF it's easy, but on universal windows app I didn't 
found a solution.

The resources file within on Resources folder in my solution, while the page it's in view folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UWP you can use `x:Uid` directive to associate a control with a string resource identifier:

```
<Button x:Uid="mylabel" Name="btnUpdate" .... Command="{Binding add}" />
```

Please refer to MSDN for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest